# SUM Union All as subquery on select statement

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `quiz`, `comment`, `question`.
All of them have a foreign key to `activity` named `activityID`.

I want to `sum` the amount of entries on each table in a single query, returning for all activities the respective `sum`.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT
    `activity`.`id` AS `activityID`,
    `activity`.`name`,
    (SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `quiz` WHERE `quiz`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id`

        UNION ALL

        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `comment` WHERE `comment`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id`

        UNION ALL

        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `question` WHERE `question`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id`
    ) `union`) AS `interactions`
FROM
    `activity`
WHERE 1
    AND `activity`.`eventID` = 1234
GROUP BY `activity`.`id`
ORDER BY `interactions` DESC
```

It does not work because `activity`.`id` is not found in the nested subquery. Is it possible to add this value to the nested subquery scope? Or even better, is there a simpler way of doing this without running three separate subqueries and adding them?

This is the best solution I have so far (without the use of `UNION`):

```
SELECT
    `activity`.`id` AS `activityID`,
    `activity`.`name`,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
      FROM `quiz` WHERE `quiz`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id` ) +
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
      FROM `comment` WHERE `comment`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id` ) +
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
      FROM `question` WHERE `question`.`activityID` = `activity`.`id` ) AS `interactions`
FROM
    `activity`
WHERE 1
    AND `activity`.`eventID` = 1234
GROUP BY `activity`.`id`
ORDER BY `interactions` DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post sample data and desired results. Thanks

Comment: What's the reason for `WHERE 1 AND ...`?

Comment: Just for better readability of the query. There is no sample since the query does not work. It should just return three columns, one with activity id, other with activity name and lastly a sum of all union set.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all the tables and get the count.

```
SELECT
    `activity`.`id` AS `activityID`,
    `activity`.`name`,
    SUM(I.count) as interactions
FROM
    `activity` A INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT `quiz`.`activityID`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `quiz` 
        GROUP BY `quiz`.`activityID`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `comment`.`activityID`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `comment`
        GROUP BY `comment`.`activityID`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `question`.`activityID`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `question`
        GROUP BY `question`.`activityID`
    ) interactioncounts I on A.id = I.activityID
WHERE 1
    AND `activity`.`eventID` = 1234
GROUP BY `activity`.`id`
ORDER BY `interactions` DESC
```

Comment: I need to use `union` as stated in the question -- there is a huge drawback on performance using `inner join` for this specific task.

Comment: You didn't say there was a drawback of inner join in the question and were asking for a simpler solution so I posted this. You can move you sub query with union from select to the from part to be able to use the activity ID. I can update the answer in about an hour or so.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Changed the query to use union like you have. The drawback here is that it is calculating the totals for all activityIds. Let me know if that is a major concern. I am trying to think of a solution that will avoid this.

Comment: I came to realize that for this specific problem, the fastest way is to add several subqueries in the `SELECT` statement filtered by the `WHERE ??.activityID = activity.id` clause. Since I have millions of entries on each table, `UNION ALL` without any `WHERE` clause is not the smartest choice.

Comment: I edited my question with the best solution I have so far. Thanks for your help!